# Prove that f(T) = Ω(l log l) for any l-leaf binary tree T

Tags: binary-trees

I want to prove this:
For any binary tree T, let f(T) denote the sum of the depths of all
of the leaves of T. (The root is at depth 0, the children of the root are at depth 1, the
grandchildren of the root are at depth 2, etc)
Prove that f(T) = Ω(l log l) for any l-leaf binary tree T.
Any suggestions?

Comment: I suggest to ask a [Good Homework Question](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1286).

Answer (score 0):

You can show that $f(T) \ge l \log l$ by induction on the height of $T$.
If the height of $T$ is $0$ then the claim is true since the only  tree of height $0$ consists of a single node and $f(T) = 1 \log 1 = 0$.

If the height of $T$ is at least $1$, then let $r$ be the root of $T$ and call $T_1$ (resp. $T_2$) be the subtree of $T$ rooted in the left (resp. right) child of $r$. (Notice that we can assume that both $T_1$ and $T_2$ exist, otherwise the claim follows immediately by applying the induction hypothesis on the subtree rooted in the unique child of $r$).

Let $l$, $l_1$, and $l_2$ be the number of leaves of $T$, $T_1$ and $T_2$, respectively.
$$
\begin{align*}
f(T) &= f(T_1) + f(T_2) + l  \ge l_1 \log l_1 + l_2 \log l_2 + l
= l_1 (1 + \log l_1) + l_2 (1 + \log l_2). 
\end{align*}
$$

Defining $\varphi(x) = x(1+ \log x)$, we have $f(T) \ge \varphi(l_1) + \varphi(l_2)$ . Since $\varphi(x)$ is a convex function, we can use [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality) to write:
$$
f(T) \ge \varphi(l_1) + \varphi(l_2) \ge 2 \cdot \varphi\left(\frac{l_1 + l_2}{2}\right) = 2 \cdot \varphi\left( \frac{l}{2} \right) = 2 \cdot \frac{l}{2}\left( 1 + \log \frac{l}{2} \right) = l\log l.
$$

Comment: Thanks, Steven. This does help me to get an understanding.